# SQL query to find total spent by a customer that has ordered between two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find the list of clients that have ordered between date1 and date2, and get their client name, contact, email, Total spent all time (not just between date 1 and date 2, and number of orders all time.

The issue I'm having is that it only sums and counts the orders between date 1 and date 2. I want those two columnns to be free of the date1 and date2.

```
declare @date1 as datetime, @date2 as dateTime

set @date1 = '12/1/2018'
set @date2 = '1/1/2019'

select
cl.BusinessName,
MAX(fn.FirstName) as Contact,
MAX(em.Email) as Email,
SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
count(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders

from Orders ord
Join Clients cl on ord.ClientID = cl.RID
Join Staffs fn on ord.StaffID = fn.RID
Join Staffs em on ord.StaffID = em.RID
where NOT OrderStatus = 6 and NOT cl.BusinessName = 'Wildcard' and isdraft = 0 and entydate between @date1 and @Date2 
Group by cl.BusinessName
```

Comment: You'll have to first, in a subquery, get a list of customers that ordered between those two dates. Then in this main query you can add to your existing WHERE clause:  `WHERE cl.ID IN (<the query you write to get the list of customers that ordered between the two dates>)`.  We could help out more if you shared your table schemas and maybe some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the total and count values in a `subquery` and add it to the script with CliendId link. As much as I understand you need something like that :

```
DECLARE @date1 AS DATETIME
      , @date2 AS DATETIME

SET @date1 = '12/1/2018'
SET @date2 = '1/1/2019'

SELECT
    cl.BusinessName
    ,MAX(fn.FirstName) as Contact
    ,MAX(em.Email) as Email
    --SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
    --COUNT(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders
    ,OT.numOrders
    ,OT.Total
FROM Orders ord
JOIN Clients cl on ord.ClientID = cl.RID
JOIN Staffs fn on ord.StaffID = fn.RID
JOIN Staffs em on ord.StaffID = em.RID
JOIN (SELECT CliendId,
            SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
            COUNT(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders
     FROM Orders
     WHERE NOT OrderStatus=6
     GROUP BY CliendId) OT ON Ord.CliendId = OT.CliendId
WHERE   NOT OrderStatus = 6 
    AND NOT cl.BusinessName = 'Wildcard' 
    AND isdraft = 0 
    AND entydate between @date1 and @Date2 
GROUP BY cl.BusinessName
        ,OT.numOrders
        ,OT.Total
```